# How to insert/update [Binary][1] value into DB column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a binary that look like this

`CRN=$\x00\x00\x00\x06\x03 \x00\x00\x00\x01`

I want it to be saved in DB like this

`update table set column='CRN=$\x00\x00\x00\x06\x03 \x00\x00\x00\x01';`

But apparently I think the above is not correct what should I do to insert the following in DB.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-binary.html), you will need to use one of two possible escape sequences.

Both start with `E'\`.  If you use the hex option, you append `\x` followed by your data in hex representation. Or you could use the ASCII-friendly format where you only have to escape the octets for the non-printable characters by outputting the octal values, e.g. `\000`. This is assuming you have a `bytea` column to store the binary data.

Your data seems to be a mixture of raw binary data and printable characters like `CRN=$` so it's really up to you.